# Get the best fit circle if radius is specified (constrained)

Tags: circles, least-squares

I am trying to get a least-square circles fit. That requires $(x_c, y_c,r)$. I know that for that the system $S = \sum_{i=1}^n{[(x_i-x_c)^2 + (y_i - b)^2 - r^2]^2}$. The way to do this is to equate the partial derivatives of the unknowns $(\partial S / \partial x_c, \partial S / \partial y_c, \partial S / \partial r)$ to $0$ and solve the system of equations.

What to do when $r$ is known? My solution gives a system with two <s>quadratic</s> equations of order $(x_c^3, y_c^3)$ and I was wondering if there is an easier way. Should I move to a numerical solution?

Comment: It is much more complex than two quadratics : write the derivatives wrt $x_c$ and $y_c$ for $n=4$. Optimization would not be hard.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Could you please expand a bit on "much more complex than quadratics"? I get a system of two equations of type: $ax_c^2 + bx + cy_c^2 + dy + e = 0$. Also, could you push me a bit further towards the not-so-hard Optimization?

Comment: So I made an error. It is much more complex than quadratics. I get polynomials of degree 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote, you have $n$ data points $(x_,y_i)$ and you want to minimize

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big[(X-x_i)^2 + (Y-y_i)^2 - R^2\Big]^2$$ As usual, we need reasonable estimates of $(X,Y)$.

In a first step, consider the $n$ equations
$$F_i=(X-x_i)^2 + (Y-y_i)^2 - R^2=0$$ and buid the $\frac{1}2 n(n-1)$ equations
$$G_{ij}=F_i-F_j=2(x_j-x_i)X+2(y_j-y_i)Y=(x_j^2+y_j^2)-(x_i^2+y_i^2)$$ where $i$ varies from $1$ to $(n-1)$ and $j$ from $(i+1)$ to $n$. This is a very simple problem.

For illustration, using the data taken from [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/35472611.pdf) (page $2$). this gives
$X_0=3.06030$ and $Y_0=0.743607$ which are almost exactly the results obtained using  Gruntz's procedure.

Now, we can go back to the original problem which means that we need to solve
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial X}=4\sum_{i=1}^n (X-x_i)\Big[(X-x_i)^2 + (Y-y_i)^2 - R^2\Big]=0$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial Y}=4\sum_{i=1}^n (Y-y_i)\Big[(X-x_i)^2 + (Y-y_i)^2 - R^2\Big]=0$$ which is very simple using Newton-Raphson method starting with $(X_0,Y_0)$ as initial guesses.

Using these values for a few values of $R$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
R & X & Y \\
 3.7 &  3.11165 & 0.800459 \\
 3.8 &  3.10106 & 0.788820 \\
 3.9 &  3.08933 & 0.775878 \\
 4.0 &  3.07628 & 0.761420 \\
 4.1 &  3.06172 & 0.745189 \\
 4.2 &  3.04537 & 0.726870 \\
 4.3 &  3.02693 & 0.706070
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This has helped a lot. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Maaz. Glad to help ! This is the first time in my loooong life working with a given radius. As you see, it is not very difficult. Cheers :-)

Comment: My actual problem was a bit different, actually. I was calculating the roundness of a curve (given by a set of points) by taking two sections of the same curve and fitting it with a circle. Doing it with a variable radius gave a greater distance between the two center points, so I wanted to try it this way.