# Position of best-fit circle center with defined Radius

Tags: circles, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the center point of a best fit circle, based on points in XY where the radius is defined. I have read the post of [Get the best fit circle if radius is specified (constrained)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246653/get-the-best-fit-circle-if-radius-is-specified-constrained/4250768#4250768) but fail to understand the calculation steps needed.

What I have is points in XY (measured) and I know what the radius should be. So my function is not looking for minimizing the residuals but rather fitting a circle with defined radius through these given points. I'm only interested in the results for X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem totally formal, the shortest distance between a point  $(x_i,y_i)$ and the circle of radius $R$ centered at $(X,Y)$ is given by
$$d_i=\left|\sqrt{(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2}-R\right|$$ So, we want to minimize
$$\color{red}{\Phi(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n \Big[\sqrt{(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2}-R\Big]^2}$$ Computing the derivatives and setting them equal to $0$, we then need to solve the equations
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-X) \left(\sqrt{(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2}-R\right)}{\sqrt{(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2}}=0}$$
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(y_i-Y) \left(\sqrt{(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2}-R\right)}{\sqrt{(x_i-X)^2+(y_i-Y)^2}}=0}$$ which are highly nonlinear which means that, at least in principle, a reasonable guess of $(X,Y)$ is required to start iterations. If you have it, no problem using Newton-Raphson method. What I gave in the first part of my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246653/get-the-best-fit-circle-if-radius-is-specified-constrained/4250768#4250768) is just a simple way to obtain this estimate (notice that $R$ is not present in this part) while the second part is an approximation of the formal problem as I set it here.

Using the same data points, taken frol page $2$ in [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/35472611.pdf), the first part gave as estimates $X_0=3.06030$ and $Y_0=0.743607$. These will be used to the full process for a few values of $R$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
R & X_{\text{previous}} & Y_{\text{previous}}& X_{\text{actual}}& Y_{\text{actual}} \\
 3.7 & 3.11165 & 0.800459 &  3.10985 & 0.810044 \\
 3.8 & 3.10106 & 0.788820 &  3.09472 & 0.795389 \\
 3.9 & 3.08933 & 0.775878 &  3.07880 & 0.779987 \\
 4.0 & 3.07628 & 0.761420 &  3.06201 & 0.763781 \\
 4.1 & 3.06172 & 0.745189 &  3.04431 & 0.746706 \\
 4.2 & 3.04537 & 0.726870 &  3.02560 & 0.728695 \\
 4.3 & 3.02693 & 0.706070 &  3.00583 & 0.709670
\end{array}
\right)$$

As you can see, the results are not identical but sufficiently close for practical purposes.

If you have an optimizer, then attack directly the problem of the minimization of $\Phi(X,Y)$ without any guess. If the errors are not too large, it should converge like a charm (you can do it using Excel solver).